# Camel sending multiple message, message remains uncommitted. How to commit

Tags: java, apache-camel

In a single route I am trying to loop and send multiple message to the final queue. But I see the messages are Uncommitted in the queue. The messages get committed only when my route processing is complete.

I want to commit the message in camel as soon as it is put in the queue.

Sample Route:

```
<route >    
<from uri="queue1" />
<process ref="Processor1" />
<to uri="direct:loop" /> 
</route>
<route>
<from uri="direct:loop"/>
<loop>
<constant>5</constant>
<process ref="Processor2"/>
<to uri="queue2"/>
</loop>
</route>
```

For the above route I need to send the message set in exchange.out in processor2 and send it 5 times.

The count of the message in the destination queue is 5, but while debugging I see that the messages sent remain uncommitted.

Comment: The queue that you are referring to , is this a Jms queue or Seda

Answer (score 2):

I found that the problem was due to transaction in Camel. in and out is considered one transaction. So all my messages were going to the queue but as uncommitted messages. To solve the issue I used JMS propogations PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW.

This solved my problem. Anyone having a better suggestion.